# Changing text of prompt based on link clicked by user

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a site that has a queue of "to do" items, which users can edit, claim, or mark as finished.  I want a simple prompt when the user clicks the link to perform one of those actions that says "are you sure you want to [action] this item?".  I know I can write a javascript function for each and use "onclick", but is there a nice way to write one function that fills in the action being done?

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='complete'>
        <a href='submit.php?request=$request_index'><img src='images/completeCheck.gif'/></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href='claim.php?request=$request_index'><img src='images/claimStar.gif'/></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes there is. Please post the relevent HTML

Comment: added.  sorry, wasn't sure it was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working examples: [Vanilla Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/bPPEG/1/) or [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/W8CRf/)

Add the class areyousure, and the text you want in the question to each anchor as a `rel` attribute.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='complete'>
        <a class='areyousure' href='submit.php?request=$request_index' rel='complete check'><img src='images/completeCheck.gif'/></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class='areyousure' href='claim.php?request=$request_index' rel='claim star'><img src='images/claimStar.gif'/></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then use this javascript to construct the question and if the user presses cancel it will return false, preventing the action.

```
var areyousures = document.getElementsByClassName('areyousure');
for (i in areyousures) {
    var item = areyousures[i];  
    item.onclick=function(){
       var q='Are you sure you want to ' + this.rel + ' this item?';
       if (!confirm(q)) return false; 
    }
}
```

If you use jQuery

```
$('.areyousure').on('click', function(){
    var q='Are you sure you want to ' + this.rel + ' this item?';
    if (!confirm(q)) return false;
})
```

Why `rel`? Because it's valid HTML and you're not already using it. Normally I'd use jQuery always so would assign a data tag instead.

Comment: this is perfect, thanks.  the vanilla javascript solution works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to validate stop the link processing if the user says no, something like:

```
$('a').click(function(evt) {
   var res = confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + $(this).text());
    if (!res) {
       evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I've posted a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dtymH/1/

Comment: OP hasn't said they want this answer as jQuery and there is no jQuery tag.

Comment: Sure, jQuery boils down to plain js under the hood, but I wouldn't try to recreate its functionality. You could write a function that loops over all of the links and adds a click handler to it, but jQuery already does that for you.

Comment: I didn't have the html in there at first, but you can see now that I'm using images instead of text to provide the links.  Would this function work with an image (maybe using alt text), or does it have to be text?

Comment: you can get whatever attribute you would like.  if you're using html 5,  you can use a  custom data-*   tag  to  specify the text